# List item background like Play Store

Tags: android, listview, background

I have specifically requested that the background of the items in a ListView be equal to the background items listed in Play Store. Like this:

[image]

So far I try this drawables:

```
@android:drawable/alert_light_frame
@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame
@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light
```

And this layer-list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="#99D3D3D3"/>
         <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="1.1dp"
    android:right="1.1dp"
    android:top="0.8dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="#fafafa"/>
       <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

They are similar to what I need, but not equals. The closest is the layer-list, but does not have the blur effect int the shape shadow.

Comment: You must use layer list for that please see the answer I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper is to use Cards which have default behavior of shadow and rounded corners.Play store is using Card with RecyclerView. These are very helpful links below:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

Best way to use [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)

Sample Example  [how to use CardView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

---

You can use this. This may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Close enough, I think I can get what I need on that basis. Thank you.